# Use ppk key when cloning a git repo

Tags: git

I need to clone repo from git, but I do not know how to use ppk key when I do this. 
Git asks a password in console, but I have a key. 
I moved from windows and used there tortoiseGit, where it can be possible to just provide a path to the key.

So, how can I insert this key while cloning a repo throught console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path to the key can be added in your ssh config, usually located at `~/.ssh/config`.

```
host myrepo.com
HostName myrepo.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
User git
```

More details [here](https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use).

You might also have to convert your ppk key to OpenSSH format using puttygen in `putty-tools` package. This can be done with the following commands for private/public key:

```
puttygen mykey.ppk -O private-openssh -o id_dsa
puttygen mykey.ppk -O public-openssh -o id_dsa.pub
```

More info about this [here](https://superuser.com/questions/232362/how-to-convert-ppk-key-to-openssh-key-under-linux).